# Changing size of alluvial plot boxes to include larger text in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggalluvial

I made an alluvial plot but I noticed that my labels are difficult to read in darker colour boxes. Ultimately, I want to have larger sized font, which means I also want taller size boxes. You will notice that `Landuse Management` and `controlled + no receiver` do not fit inside the boxes, which is what I am trying to fix. Here is my sample data

```
df = structure(list(Total_Publications = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Method_Group = c("Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "BRUV + Both", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Controlled + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "BRUV + Both", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Controlled + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Controlled + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "BRUV + Both", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Controlled + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "BRUV + Both", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"BRUV + Both", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Controlled + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "BRUV + Both", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "BRUV + Both", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Controlled + No Receiver", "BRUV + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "BRUV + Both", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Controlled + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"BRUV + Both", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"BRUV + Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + Receiver", "Animal Borne + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver", 
"Animal Borne + No Receiver", "Stationary + No Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Stationary + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", "Controlled + Receiver", 
"Controlled + Receiver", "Stationary + Receiver"), Topic = c("Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Landuse Management", 
"Conservation Methods", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Other Drivers", 
"Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Other Drivers", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Conservation Methods", "Conservation Methods", "Landuse Management", 
"Landuse Management", "Landuse Management", "Conservation Methods", 
"Other Drivers", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Conservation Methods", "Landuse Management", 
"Landuse Management", "Conservation Methods", "Conservation Methods", 
"Conservation Methods", "Conservation Methods", "Conservation Methods", 
"Conservation Methods", "Conservation Methods", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Conservation Methods", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", "Behavioural Ecology", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", 
"Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Other Drivers", "Conservation Methods", 
"Behavioural Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", 
"Reproductive Ecology", "Reproductive Ecology", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", "Methodological", 
"Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", "Fisheries Managemenet", 
"Fisheries Managemenet")), row.names = c(NA, -230L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And here is my code to run the alluvial plot

```
library("viridis")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library("ggalluvial")



plot = ggplot(df,
              aes(y = Total_Publications, axis1 = Method_Group, axis2 = Topic)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Method_Group, color = after_scale(fill)), 
                width = 1/3.5, alpha = 1) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE, begin = 0.25, end = 1) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/3.5, alpha = 0, reverse = TRUE, color = "white", linewidth = 2) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size= 7, color = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Device Combination", "Ecological Theme"), 
                   expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y= element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20, colour = "black"))

plot
```

Ideally I would have it look something like the image below created by "Matley, J.K., Klinard, N.V., Larocque, S.M. et al. Making the most of aquatic animal tracking: a review of complementary methods to bolster acoustic telemetry. Rev Fish Biol Fisheries 33, 35–54 (2023). [https://doi.org/10.1007/s11160-022-09738-3"](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11160-022-09738-3%22), where both sides of my graph look like the left side of this graph in terms of different colour lettering to make the words pop across the colour gradient and spacing of the boxes where they are not connected [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is really just about device size. If you save your plot like this:

```r
ggsave('myplot.png', device = ragg::agg_png, 
        width = unit(20, 'in'), height = unit(20, 'in'))
```

You get

[image]

Note that we have simply made the plot taller to accommodate the text. The text looks like it has shrunk relative to the plot, but that's because the plot is now *massive*.
If you want to fit the text in the boxes, but fit all the boxes in to the plot at the correct size, you need to make sure the plot is large enough to accommodate the text (or that the text is small enough to fit).

Comment: Right, so there is no way to make the boxes larger in relaton to each other? As you mentioned I have to trade-off between text looking smaller but fitting inside the box, or text being larger and not fitting inside the box...

Comment: From a purely geometric perspective, if you only have a certain amount of space then the text has to be the right size to fit in it. It's a bit like asking "how do I fit the whole works of Shakespeare on the back of a postage stamp?" You either need tiny letters or a huge stamp.